# Hide rows and columns if cell font color

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have part of code which should hide rows & columns if cell font color is not VBRed.
It works but hides all rows and columns within range including those with font color VBRed. Any clues what is wrong here? Same happa

```
With shtDE
    For s = DErow + 2 To lrDE
        For ss = DEcolIndx + 2 To LcolDE
    
            Set rng1 = .Range(.Cells(s, ss), .Cells(s, ss))
            If rng1.Font.Color = vbRed > 0 Then
                rng1.EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Else
                rng1.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        Next ss
    Next s
End With


With shtDE
    For ss = DEcolIndx + 2 To LcolDE
        For s = DErow + 2 To lrDE
            Set rng1 = .Range(.Cells(s, ss), .Cells(s, ss))
            If rng1.Font.Color = vbRed > 0 Then
                rng1.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            Else
                rng1.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            End If
        Next s
    Next ss
End With
```

Comment: Is the red applied with conditional formatting?

Comment: @BigBen No. it  is being applied with below code.           Else
    xDEa = Application.Index(DE_Range, Application.Match(SM_Lookup_Value1, DE_Lookup_Values1_Range, 0), Application.Match(SM_Lookup_Values_LDAPs, DE_Lookup_Values_LDAPs_Range, 0)).Address
        shtDE.Range(xDEa).Font.Color = vbRed
            shtDE.Range(xDEa).Interior.ColorIndex = 22
End If

Comment: What is the point of the `> 0` in your `If` statement? That will likely evaluate to `False`.

Comment: You're mixing `ColorIndex` and `Color`, don't do that. But yeah the real problem is the `> 0`. It is always `True` that `vbRed > 0`. So your `If` is equivalent to `If rng1.Font.Color = True`.

Comment: @Professor Pantsless
 thanks, that has left from my previous try with count if. Already remove but seems like it still not work

Comment: Are you trying to hide rows/columns where any cell font is not red, or where all cell fonts are not red? Agree with @BigBen, the macro will hide and show multiple times but will end with the last cell in the row/column it checks.

Comment: `Set rng1 = .Range(.Cells(s, ss), .Cells(s, ss))` is redundant and equivalent to just `.Cells(s, ss)`.

Comment: @Professor Pantsless
thank you for your tips, correct even when i remove >0 It still no showing correct rows and columns. I need to write something like Count if that would check all cells in row and if result would be >0 than entire row won't be hidden, same later with columns. However not sure if i can use Count If when searching for font colors ?

Comment: I think I understand, but I still need to express it in simple terms to make sure we are on the same page: The end goal is for all cells with vbRed color font to be visible, correct? Thus you are only hiding rows/columns if the entire row/column is non-red font? In this case the simplest modification to your code would be to add `Exit For` after both `.Hidden = False` lines of code (disclaimer: untested). I might suggest something different if performance time is in question (there could be some unnecessary hiding going on), but this should get the end result.

Comment: @Professor Pantsless
 Thank You. Just added Exit For and it works as expected. Thank  you both for advices. Really appreciate.

Comment: Added an answer to summarize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the goal is to have all cells with vbRed as font color (and the rows/columns which contain those cells), there are 2 main points to address in your code:

1. The `If` statements have a trailing `> 0` which will cause them to evaluate to `False`.
2. The code loops through all cells and the end result will be based on the last cell it checks.

The following should address both issues:

```
With shtDE
    For s = DErow + 2 To lrDE
        For ss = DEcolIndx + 2 To LcolDE
    
            Set rng1 = .Range(.Cells(s, ss), .Cells(s, ss))
            If rng1.Font.Color = vbRed Then
                rng1.EntireRow.Hidden = False
                Exit For 'once a cell is found leave the row visible and go to next row
            Else
                rng1.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        Next ss
    Next s
End With


With shtDE
    For ss = DEcolIndx + 2 To LcolDE
        For s = DErow + 2 To lrDE
            Set rng1 = .Range(.Cells(s, ss), .Cells(s, ss))
            If rng1.Font.Color = vbRed Then
                rng1.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                Exit For ' same as above but for column
            Else
                rng1.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            End If
        Next s
    Next ss
End With
```